# Pandas dataframe: group by columnn and let duplicates of this columnn span several rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping, pivot-table

I have a dataframe and I would like to group the elements by one of the columns, and where this columns has identical elements I would like to make them into one big element (spanning several rows). Finally I need to make it into latex code.

Say I have something like

```
import pandas as pd
import random
table=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,2,2,3,6,6],'b':[-6,-4,-3,-1,0,-1,-2],'c':random.sample(xrange(30), 7)},index=range(7))
```

giving the dataframe

```
|   | a | b | c |
-----------------
| 0 | 1 |-6 | 19|
-----------------
| 1 | 2 |-4 | 12|
-----------------
| 2 | 2 |-3 | 16|
-----------------
| 3 | 2 |-1 | 23|
-----------------
| 4 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
-----------------
| 5 | 4 |-1 | 21|
-----------------
| 6 | 4 |-2 | 15|
```

And now I'd like to group this by column a giving something like (whether it keeps the index in the leftmost column doesn't matter):

```
| a | b | c |
-------------
| 1 |-6 | 19|
-------------
|   |-4 | 12|
     --------
| 2 |-3 | 16|
    ---------  
|   |-1 | 23|
-------------
| 3 | 0 | 0 |
-------------
|   |-1 | 21|
    ---------
| 4 |-2 | 15|
```

Where some elements span several rows; hopefully the above explains what I mean. I almost get this by using

```
summary=pd.pivot_table(table, index=['a','b'],values=['c'])
```

However this makes it multi-index (?), i.e.

```
|   |   | c |
-------------
| a | b |   |
-------------
| 1 |-6 | 19|
    ...
```

which gives a problem when using

```
summary.to_latex()
```

to get latex code. In addition, with several value columns, `pd.pivot_table()` orders them in a new way while I would like to keep the order from the original DataFrame. (Note that this would work even worse if there were ever any rows that had both the same a and b, but that is not the case for my data)

Is there a way to either flatten the header rows of the pivot table into one header row, and to keep the order of the value columns? Or another way to do this altogether? I have looked into some other options like `pd.groupby()` without finding anything.

Comment: I think if use `summary=pd.pivot_table(table, index=['a','b'],values=['c'])` get multiindex (because 2 columns `a` and `b` are set to index) and how let sorted df custom way explain [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33899552/2901002).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want latex code which has `multirow` effects. The `pivot_table` approach doesn't give you that. In fact, I don't think `pd.DataFrame.to_latex()` will have that `multirow`/merged cell for latex. You will need to write it yourself.

If you don't need merged cells and instead it's OK to have blank cells, you can try something like:

```
table=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,2,2,3,6,6],'b':[-6,-4,-3,-1,0,-1,-2],'c':random.sample(xrange(30), 7)},index=range(7))

table.loc[table['a'].diff() == 0, 'a'] = ''

print table.to_latex(index=False)

#Output
\begin{tabular}{lrr}
\toprule
 a &  b &   c \\
\midrule
 1 & -6 &  23 \\
 2 & -4 &   2 \\
   & -3 &  20 \\
   & -1 &  21 \\
 3 &  0 &   5 \\
 6 & -1 &  17 \\
   & -2 &  22 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```